# Google Actions DialogFlow Add Item To Cart

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-home

I have an app that helps users find the perfect TV. It ask questions like size, cost, features, etc. Once they provide all the parameters, I send the request to my fulfillment webhook (node server using dialogflow SDK), run my logic, and return the name of the perfect tv for them. I'm using a list of TVs from Walmart.com.

For this example imagine the winning TV is a Samsung 40" HDTV UPC:12345. How can I add this item to their Walmart cart.

Thanks.

Comment: What code are you trying to use to add something to the cart? Does Wallmart have an API for their cart? (Is this a DialogFlow question or a Wallmart question?)

Comment: I'm currently not using any code. I can't find any examples in the Google actions or dialogflow sdk about adding item to cart. Walmart has an API for their cart (https://developer.walmartlabs.com/docs ) but, I'm assuming adding to their cart via Google home is different. Do you know of any examples? Would each retailer be different? I assumed all retailers worked the same but you added in the merchant id.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this the wrong way. Walmart items are hosted by Google Express. Therefore, you need to add your item to the Google Express Cart, not the Walmart cart.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48810781/add-google-express-item-to-cart-from-3rd-party-google-assistant-actions-app for how to add Google express item to cart.